# Using NuGet 4.0 with VSTS?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore, azure-pipelines-build-task

Upgraded our ASP.Net Core project (using full .Net Framework) from .json project to .csproj format, using VisualStudio 2017, and the project builds and runs just fine locally.

From what I understand NuGet 4 is bundled with VisualStudio 2017.

Trying to build this using VisualStudioTeamServices fails on the "Nuget installer" task, as we can only select version 3.5 of NuGet for this task. (And yes, Visual Studio 2017 is installed on the build server, and the agent has been updated to have the capabilities updated)

There is an argument to enter a custom path for nuget in this task, could this be used? Or do we have to wait for an updated version of the Nuget installer build task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anybody else has the same problem, I figured out that we no longer need the "Nuget installer" step. Simply add "/t:restore" as an argument to MsBuild.